# Generate a list of QR-code with lua

Tags: lua, luacode

I want to generate a list of digit sequences, where a part of a sequence is a counter and another one is generated depending on this counter. My MnotWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcommand{\Digits}[2]{
    \luaexec{
        a = #1+#2
        b = #1*#2
        tex.sprint(\luastring{#1#2 a b})
    }
}

\newcommand{\PrintQR}

\begin{document}


    \foreach\AA in{1,...,10}{
        \foreach\BB in{1,...,2}{
            \renewcommand{\PrintQR}{\Digits{\AA}{\BB}}
            \PrintQR
            %\qrcode{\PrintQR}
        }
    }

\end{document}
```

There are two problems:

1. Instead of the values of `a` and `b` the I get the letters themselves.
2. If I uncomment the line `\qrcode` I get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't get which output you want, but don't use \luaexec in this case. It is not expandable. I also doubt that you need \luastring, but if you use it don't put variables in its argument.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{luacode}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\newcommand{\Digits}[2]{%
    \directlua{
        a = #1 + #2;
        b = #1 * #2;
        tex.sprint("#1#2="..a..b)
    }%
}


\newcommand{\PrintQR}

\begin{document}


    \foreach\AA in{1,...,10}{
        \foreach\BB in{1,...,2}{
            \renewcommand{\PrintQR}{\Digits{\AA}{\BB}}
            \PrintQR
            \qrcode{\Digits{\AA}{\BB}}
        }
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, works as needed. I just didn't need the `=`.